# Java : How to remove from Ecache?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, ehcache, sap-commerce-cloud

This is how I'm caching data on **GET** request:

```
@Cacheable(value = "userCache", key = "T(de.hybris.platform.commercewebservicescommons.cache.CommerceCacheKeyGenerator).generateKey(true,true,'DTO',#currentPage,#pageSize,#sort,#fields)")
public UsersDTO getUsers(final int currentPage, final int pageSize, final String sort,
            final String fields)
{
        // Code......
}
```

How can I delete only 'DTO' from cache for other requests for example when I trigger DELETE Request I want to remove 'DTO' ? And can we do it via annotation ?

Right now I'm doing this but I think it's removing entire userCache

```
public void updateUserCache()
    {
        final Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("userCache");
        final Ehcache ehCache = (Ehcache) cache.getNativeCache();
        ehCache.getKeys().forEach(key -> {
            cache.evict(key);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below code:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "userCache", key="#userId")
public void updateUserCache()
    {
....
...
}
```

or u can do like this

```
   if (cache.isKeyInCache(userId))
    {
        cache.remove(key);
    }
```